# Operator A is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\ell^2$ be the space of sequences $x = ( x_1, x_2, \ldots )$ such that $( || x ||_l^2)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ . Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{k\ \to \infty}a_k = 0$.  Prove that the operator $$A\colon( x_1, x_2, \ldots) \to ( a_1x_1, a_2,x_2, \ldots, a_kx_k, \ldots)$$ is compact.

*Proof:* 
Let $A_n$ be such that 
$$A_k(x_k) =
\begin{cases} 
a_k \cdot x_k & \text{if } k\le n \\
0 & \text{if } k > n
\end{cases} 
$$
Then $ A_n $ is finite ranked, hence compact. For any $ v \in \ell^2 $,
$ v = (v_0, v_1, \ldots) $
$$
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert (A-A_n)v \right\Vert^2 &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigl|\left<\bigl[(A-A_n)v\bigr]_k\right>\bigr|^2 \\
&= \sum_{k \ge n+1} |(A-A_n)v_k|^2 \\
&= \sum_{k \ge n+1}|a_k|^2 ( \left\Vert v \right\Vert_l^2) \\
&\le \sup_{k \ge n+1}|a_k|^2 ( \left\Vert v \right\Vert_l^2)
\end{align*}
$$

So $\left\Vert A-A_n \right\Vert \le \sup_{k \ge n+1}\left|a_k\right| $ and we conclude that $A_n \to A $ in norm. A norm-limit of compact operator is compact so A is compact.

Does the proof is ok ?

Comment: Yep, I think it is.

Comment: This is correct. Moreover, this operator is compact only if $a_k \to 0$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560801/compact-operator-in-ell-p/2560818#2560818

Comment: Should I prove the only if also for my problem ?

Comment: What did you mean by $( || x ||_l^2)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$? Also the 4th inequality is good (if you delete the 3rd one) but why do you have the 3rd equality "$\sum_{k\ge n+1}|a_k|^2(\|v\|_\ell^2)$"? Further, from the 3rd equality the 4th one does not follow.